# C# vs Java for Cross-Platform Game Dev

Tags: c#, java, windows, linux, mono

What would be better for PC (Windows, Linux, Mac) games?

I know Java is more mature/older and has a giant user base, but I see C# (Mono) slowly rising and showing that it has a growing user base as well.

I've seen lots of games written in Java like Minecraft, Runescape etc. (Haven't really seen any popular C# games!)

But what would be better?

More Info(Ideas for games I'm going to make): 3D games (FPS, Racer, TPS?) and maybe 2D games (Platformer?)

Comment: Terraria is a popular C# game.  And Java would *probably* be a bit better for cross platform, simply because it's designed for it (Mono might have occasional problems on some platforms)

Comment: @thedaian while I agree with you, I must say the C# tooling is much nicer to work with, imo.

Comment: Too vague, too general, too subjective. Given that the 2 languages are very similar anyway it's almost a religious question.

Comment: agreed@kylotan. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer Java.

Because:

- Java have applets for web-based games (sliverlight is not already installed by default). Applets are very good for demos.
- Java is already installed on Mac OS and on most Linux distributions.
- You can run Java in mono or even compiling Java Code to x86 Code "http://www.mono-project.com/Java" and there is gcj also.
- More and more people started to use java for games because of android today has the biggest market share in the mobile OS market.
- I like to use Eclipse

This is just my point of view.
Use whatever works best for you.

You can look at some compaction between java and c#:

http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx as a test I checked that sites 'new' page so do be careful with it. Lots looks right though

Comment: I do love the idea of Android for Java, but I found out Mono could work on Android which made me happy until I found out I need to pay over $300 before I can do so.

Comment: I really wouldn't use mono for android if you want to make games.  From what I understand, it's running the mono runtime in the background, which in combination with also running the dalvikvm, on a device which is already fairly constrained, just sounds like a recipe for slow.  I mean, it's probably fast enough for regular apps, and the occasional number crunch, but not so much for games.